# Converting .apk into .aab

Tags: apk, kivy-language, google-play-console, kivymd, bundletool

I created a mobile application using kivy framework, then I converted (.py+.kv) into .apk using buildozer, then  I found out that google console accept only .abb.
I need to convert apk or py to abb

bundletools does not work

```
java -jar bundletool-all-1.15.6.jar build-bundle --modules=~/key_store_0/myapp-0.1-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a-debug.apk --output=~/key_store_0/app_bundle.aab
```